# Why my bell curve is flat

Tags: r, normal-distribution, histogram

I have a data coming from temperature sensor. I wanted to plot histogram with a normal distribution overlay on top. I'd expect the overlay to be not flat, but it is a flat line for some reason. Why?

I have an idea that this is because the data is somewhat discrete. Sensor registeres temperature approximately, so it rounds up to 0.2 C. Naturally the data domain has spaces. My data has a few thousands points, but when I do `unique(temperature$VALUE)` - I receive 70 points. Could this be a problem? If yes, how can I fix my R code?

```
ggplot(temperature, aes(VALUE)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.05) + 
  stat_function(geom="line", fun=dnorm,   lwd = 1, colour="red", args=list(mean = mean(temperature$VALUE), sd = sd(temperature$VALUE)))
```

[image]

I'm not that good in stat, so sorry if I'm doing something very weird, please explain if that's true.

Comment: You have to specify the mean and the standard deviation of `dnorm`. Here you draw the bell curve for $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$, which is indeed "flat" between $24$ and $28$.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Ah, you are right. I have mistakenly removed the argument. Please see update, I've added it. The result is still the same

Comment: look [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_distributions_(ggplot2)/) or [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-make-a-histogram-with-ggplot2/). You need to use the `aes(y=..density..)`. This is a question for stackoverflow by the way.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks, that helped. I was not sure whether it is a programming, or my understanding of math, that's why I've posted it here. I'll be smarter next time

Comment: Are you only asking how to get your red line to plot differently, or are you wondering about the distribution of your temperatures? The former is off topic here, but the latter would be on topic.

Comment: @gung both. But I think I've got it now

Answer (score 0):

The normal density function has value range of [0,1].  And your Y axis is actually a count of frequency (more than 200).

There is no method to have 2 Y Axis on the same ggplot graph.

But you can try to convert the frequency to proportions.

Comment: Could you suggest any R code I could use? I am quite new to the topic and do not operate R so well

Comment: @Archeg dividing frequency by the total number of observations would help put the histogram on the same scale as the curve.

Comment: Thanks. That's all true, but I prefer to not to manually do that. **Stéphane Laurent** in the comments above correctly suggested to use `aes(y=..density..)` which worked

Comment: "normal density function has value range of [0,1]" - that is *not* true, density can be greater than 1, see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok